# 'unoconv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, windows, unoconv

So I am trying to convert a docx file to a pdf but when I run the command `unoconv -f pdf fileName.docx` it returns the error `'unoconv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

1. I have installed LibreOffice and believe that it is in the right place. I have not setup a listener for LibreOffice yet but this is not needed as unoconv should open its own instance. -- `C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\python.exe`
2. I believe that I have unoconv installed in the correct place. -- `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\unoconv`

One thing to note is that unoconv in the Scripts folder is named `unoconv` with no extensions, I am not sure if I need to rename it as `unoconv.exe`, `unoconv.py` or rename it all.

Comment: Windows does require that a file have an executable extension (typically `.exe`) to be recognized as executable.

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you, I was unsure if that was the cause.